# Finding common elements in arrays

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a hash whose values are arrays. I need to find the common elements of those arrays, 
ie. the elements that are present in all the arrays. So I extracted the values of the hash into 
a multidimensional array whose each row corresponds to an array in the hash. Then I took the first row 
of this matrix into another array (@arr1) and iterated through it to find if there was any element 
in arr1 that was also in the rest of the rows of the matrix. If such an element is found, it is 
pushed onto another array that contains the final list of all the elements. The code is as follows
(I hope it is clear enough):

```
sub construct_arr(my %records) {
    my $len = keys %records;
    my @matrix;
    my $i = 0;

    # Extract the values of the hash into a matrix
    foreach my $key (keys %records) {
        $matrix[$i] = $records{$key};
        $i++;   
    }

    my @arr1 = $matrix[0];
    my @final;

    # Iterate through each element of arr1
    for my $j (0..$#{$arr1[0]}) {
        my $count = 1;

        # Iterate through each row of the matrix, starting from the second
        for ( my $i = 1; $i < $len ; $i++ ) {
            my $flag = 0;

            # Iterate through each element of the row
            for my $k (0..$#{$matrix[$i]}) {
                if ($arr1[0][$j] eq $matrix[$i][$k]) {
                    $flag = 1;
                    $count++;
                }
            }

            # On finding the first instance of the element in a row, go to the next row
            if (!$flag == 1) {
                last;
            }       
        }

        # If element is in all the rows, push it on to the final array
        if ($count == $len) {
            push(@final, $arr1[0][$j]);
        }
    }
    return @final;
}
```

I know that the above works, but I would like to know if there is any other (perlish) way to do this.
I am starting to learn perl and I am very interested in knowing things that could make my work easier 
in perl as compared to other languages. If my code is the best that can be done, please let me know that
too. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [*Chris Charley's* link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10364891/622310) for calculating the intersection of arrays.

Hashes are the clear way to go for problems like this. Together with `map` and `grep` a solution can be reduced to just a few lines.

This program uses [*sundar's*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8127/sundar) data for want of anything better, and seems to do what you need.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %records = (
  a => [ qw/ A B C / ],
  b => [ qw/ C D E A / ],
  c => [ qw/ A C E / ],
);

print "$_\n" for construct_arr(\%records);

sub construct_arr {
  my $records = shift;
  my %seen;
  $seen{$_}++ for map @$_, values %$records;
  grep $seen{$_} == keys %$records, keys %seen;
}
```

**output**

```
A
C
```

---

**Edit**

I thought it may help to see a more Perlish, tidied version of your own solution.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %records = (
  a => [ qw/ A B C / ],
  b => [ qw/ C D E A / ],
  c => [ qw/ A C E / ],
);

print "$_\n" for construct_arr(\%records);

sub construct_arr {

  my $records = shift;
  my @matrix = values %$records;
  my @final;

  # iterate through each element the first row
  for my $i ( 0 .. $#{$matrix[0]} ) {

    my $count = 1;

    # look for this value in all the rest of the rows, dropping
    # out to the next row as soon as a match is found
    ROW:
    for my $j ( 1 .. $#matrix ) {
      for my $k (0 .. $#{$matrix[$j]}) {
        next unless $matrix[0][$i] eq $matrix[$j][$k];
        $count++;
        next ROW;
      }
    }

    # If element is in all the rows, push it on to the final array
    push @final, $matrix[0][$i] if $count == @matrix;
  }

  return @final;
}
```

The output is the same as for my own program, but the functionality is slightly different as mine assumes the values in each row are unique. If the sama value appears more than once my solution will break (the same applies to *sundar's*). Please let me know if that is acceptable.

Comment: @user828647: This is probably the perfect Perlish way to do this (though I personally would have preferred the return from the function to be explicit), utilizing contexts, references and subs.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I found your improvements of my code to be very instructive. Unfortunately your own solution went a bit over my head, I guess I don't know enough perl yet. Would you mind explaining how the grep command works here? I have some idea of using grep in UNIX, but I have never seen it used with hashes in perl. I will definitely study this some more.

Comment: @sundar BTW, my arrays all contain unique elements, so your code would not break. But I think simply by checking the condition `$count >= @matrix` when pushing into the final array would make the program run even if the arrays contain non-unique elements. Please let me know if this is correct.

Comment: @user828647: no, because if your data looked like `(['A', 'A'], ['B', 'B'])` the program would output both `A` and `B` because it counted them twice.

Comment: @user828647: the statement `grep $seen{$_} == keys %$records, keys %seen` is filtering the list of all keys of the hash `%seen`, allowing through only those for whom the value `$seen{$_}` is equal to the number of keys in `%$records`, i.e. the number of rows.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I think I understand now. But Perl seems to be a peculiar language, with so many ways to do the same thing...and strange syntax for all of them!

Comment: I am accepting your solution because it has the most upvotes and for your detailed explanations.

Answer (score 3):

Although the poster explained there aren't duplicates within a single array, here is my attempt which handles that case too (notice the slightly modified test data - "5" should not be printed):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %records = (
    a => [1, 2, 3],
    b => [3, 4, 5, 1],
    c => [1, 3, 5, 5]
);

my %seen;
while (my ($key, $vals) = each %records) {
    $seen{$_}{$key} = 1 for @$vals;
}

print "$_\n" for grep { keys %{$seen{$_}} == keys %records } keys %seen;
```

Comment: +1 very neat. Nice use of `each`. `%seen` should be `keys %seen` in the last line - I'll fix it.

Comment: +1 Though my present case does not have duplicates in the arrays, this might come in handy some other time. And I wish I could give you another +1 for telling me about the `each` keyword!

Answer (score 1):

You can find the size of the hash easily using `scalar(keys %hash);`

Here's an example code that does what you need:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %records = ( a => [1, 2, 3],
                b => [3, 4, 5, 1],
                c => [1, 3, 5]
              );

my %count;
foreach my $arr_ref (values %records) {
    foreach my $elem (@$arr_ref) {
        $count{$elem}++;
    }
}

my @intersection;
my $num_arrays = scalar(keys %records);
foreach my $elem (keys %count) {
    #If all the arrays contained this element, 
    #allowing for multiple entries per array
    if ($count{$elem} >= $num_arrays) {
        push @intersection, $elem;
    }
}
```

Feel free to comment if you need any clarification in this code. And the second foreach that constructs the @intersection array is written this way only for clarity - if you're learning Perl, I'd suggest you study and rewrite it using the `map` construct, since that's arguably more idiomatic Perl.

Comment: Thanks for the code! I didn't know about using @$, so I could not have figured this out myself.

Comment: I will surely accept your answer if someone does not come up with a better solution.

Comment: Someone came up with a better answer!