# Is there a way to count hash values that are also elements of an array?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have an array of elements (@codes) and some of these elements are values in a hash (%records), however the hash also has values that are not contained in the array (@codes).

Is there a way to count the number of hash keys from %records where the corresponding hash value is an element of the array @codes?  I'd like to do this without iterating through a loop if possible.  Thanks!

Comment: There is no way to do this without a loop. You can hide the loop in a grep or map if you wish though.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with grep, what would this look like?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364821/finding-common-elements-in-arrays#

Comment: How would you count something without a loop? Even in the real world, you count things with a loop. You don't count "1, 2, 397, done!" do you?

Comment: For example, if I wanted to count the number of times a sting occurred in another string I would use:

$count=()=$string1=~/$string2/g;

Just wanted to know if there is something similar for matching hash values from array elements

Comment: Perhaps what I should have said is: "There are `for` and `while` loops, and then there are ways to count things that don't look like loops (e.g. `grep`, `map`, `tr`), even though they really use loops behind the scenes. Why do you want to avoid `for` or `while` loops?"

Comment: That example is still looping, it's just hiding that it's doing so, by doing it implicitly.

Comment: Right, but it seems to iterate through it faster than with for or while loops.  I'm sure there is a reason for this but I'm not aware of it.

Comment: @Spartacus That's called "premature optimization." If you have a genuine performance problem in your code, by all means, try to find a faster method; but until you have a performance problem, and can prove that a particular section of code is your bottleneck and therefore worth tuning, you should probably focus on writing readable, maintainable code, even if that means using standard, boring `for` and `while` loops.

Comment: Originally, all the relevant info in %records was in the form of a string and I was trying to count the number of times each element in @codes occurred in the string.  This process was taking much longer than I would have liked it to, so I started playing around with finding ways to speed it up, that brought me here.

Comment: One way of making faster is implementing parallelism. That's a genuine speedup with the right class of problem.

Comment: You're right Sobrique, I have not explored that avenue yet

Comment: @Spartacus That's called an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (don't worry, they're quite common). If you had told us the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of how you're trying to solve it, we may have been able to suggest better approaches from the beginning. I would recommend asking a new question where you explain exactly what you're trying to accomplish and explain your speed constraints. There may be better approaches than using an array and a hash.

Comment: Apparently I have to wait 60 mins :/  Thank you though @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, I got a little ahead of myself trying to find a solution

Comment: @Spartacus It happens, even with experienced programmers. Now you can take that 60 minutes to draft a really great question :) Make sure to explain the actual problem you're trying to solve, e.g. "I have a file that looks like <sample input file>. It is a CSV file where column 1 holds IDs and column 2 holds names. I need to find all the IDs where the name starts with 'J'. I tried A, B, and C (<actual code snippet>), but they took more than 10 minutes to run on a 42 byte file. How can I do this more quickly?" Make sure to include sample input and your expected output. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As an example of how you'd do this with map:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %records = (
    'one'   => 1,
    'two'   => 2,
    'three' => 3,
);

my @codes = ( 'one', 'three', 'fake' );

my %seen = map { $_ => 1 } @codes;
print scalar grep ( $seen{$_}, keys(%records) );
```

But don't be under any illusions - this is still doing a loop, it's just implicit in the `map` function.

Comment: Seems like the OP wants to count the elements of `@codes` that equal a value in the hash; this simply returns the number of elements in `@codes`.

Comment: Ah yes, after checking the number of elements in @codes, ThisSuitIsBlackNot is correct.

Comment: And yes, I'm looking to count the elements of @codes that equal a value in the hash, in the fastest way possible.  If that includes a loop, implicit or not, then so be it.

Comment: Personally - if you're after fast, then I honestly wouldn't go with map/grep - they're too clever for their own good. You could always do it two ways and compare.